# do I need JavaScript for this part of PHP and CSS? or is it possible with css alone?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Hi guys all the css works for all the calculations, for add, mult, sub, div but when I display all of it, how would I change the CSS to change it to a bigger box on that click of the button called "display all". if you see my CSS code for my display block   #answers it only fits for the single number value, but how would I adjust the CSS so it can change the width and height when a user calculates much larger numbers, or display all?

this is the code here

```
<html>
    <body>
         <style><?php include "style.css" ?></style>
            <form action="index.php" method="POST">
                <table border="1">
                   <td>
                      <p>insert value one: <input type="text" name="num1"> <br>
                      <p>insert value two: <input type="text" name="num2"> <br>
                   </td>
                   <td>
                       <input type="submit" name="add" value="Addition">
                       <input type="submit" name="sub" value="Subtraction">
                       <input type="submit" name="mult" value="Multiplication">
                       <input type="submit" name="div" value="Division">
                       <input type="submit" name="all" value="Display All">
                   </td>
                 </table>
              </form>
 <div id="answers">
   <?php
    if (isset($_POST['num1']) && ($_POST['num2'])){
      $val1 = $_POST['num1'];
      $val2 =   $_POST['num2']; 
      $add = $val1+$val2;
      $sub = $val1-$val2;
      $mult = $val1*$val2;
      $div = $val1/$val2;   
    }

    if (isset($_POST['add'])){
      echo $add;
    }
    if (isset($_POST['sub'])){
      echo $sub;
    }
    if (isset($_POST['mult'])){
      echo $mult;
    }
    if (isset($_POST['div'])){
      echo $div;
    }
   if (isset($_POST['all'])){
      echo $add . "<br>" . $sub . "<br>" . $mult . "<br>" . $div . "<br>";
    }
?>

</div>  

    </body>
</html>
```

and my CSS

```
body{
  background-color:#f0f0f0;
}

table{
  margin:50px auto;
  background-color: tan;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#answers{
  margin:10px auto;
  width: 100px;
  height:30px;
  background-color: tan;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:30px;
  border: solid black 1px;
}
```

Comment: try getting rid of `width: 100px;` and adding `display:inline-block`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to set the #answers to display: table-cell and to create a wrapper div around it to display: table

For example:

// CSS

```
#answers{
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: tan;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  border: solid black 1px;
}
.answers-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
}
```

// HTML

```
<div class="answers-wrapper">
    <div id="answers">
        <?php?>
    </div>
</div>
```

This should allow the tan box to expand when your number grows bigger.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `width` (see note below) and `height`, you can try using `min-width` and `min-height` to make your box expand according to its content but never below the specified minimum values.

Here you can see a couple of examples with `min-height` only: http://jsfiddle.net/tv598/

Note that the `display: block` (which is the default for divs) sets the width to 100% by default, and although you can use `display: inline-block;` instead, it will cause your divs to appear inline and you also won't be able to center is using the auto margins.

Comment: Is that why you chose the other answer? :D Anyway, min-height is one of basic style attributes, there are also max- versions of both... Nice for limiting things.